# Tractability of the E Step of the Expectation Maximization Algorithm

Tags: expectation-maximization, marginal-distribution

To optimize a probabilistic model with latent variables, I was trying to convince myself that there are situations where computing the marginalization $p(x)$ is intractable and computing the $Q(\theta | \theta^{t})$ in the E step of the Expectation Maximization is tractable, so that the EM algorithm is useful.

Borrowing the equation from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm#The_EM_algorithm):

$$
Q(\theta | \theta^{t}) = \mathbb{E}_{Z \sim p(\cdot | X, \theta^{t})} [\log p(X, Z | \theta)]
$$

To compute $Q(\theta | \theta^{t})$, we need to know the conditional distribution $p( Z | X, \theta^{t})$ and this is computed using Bayes' theorem,

$$
p( Z | X, \theta^{t}) = \frac{p( Z, X | \theta^{t})}{p( X | \theta^{t})} = \frac{p( Z, X | \theta^{t})}{\sum_{z \in \mathcal{Z}} p( Z = z, X | \theta^{t})}
$$

My question is, if computing $p( Z | X, \theta^{t})$, more specifically $p( X | \theta^{t})$, is tractable, shouldn't computing $p( X | \theta)$ is also tractable? Then we could just use gradient ascent instead of the EM algorithm for optimizing the probabilistic model with latent variables.

There must be something wrong with my understanding. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: There are cases when the conditional expectation can be computed or approximated by Monte Carlo without $p(x|\theta)$ being available in closed form.

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you. But if $p(x | \theta)$ can be directly approximated, why can't we just directly do gradient ascent on $p(x | \theta)$ or $\log p(x | \theta)$ with respect to $\theta$ such that $p(x | \theta)$ or $\log p(x | \theta)$ is maximized? Then the EM algorithm would not be needed. If you can do Monte Carlo for EM, you can do Monte Carlo for $p(x | \theta)$ or $\log p(x | \theta)$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that in many cases, we use EM algorithms in which the observed data likelihood can be computed and thus optimized with gradient based methods.

With that said, there are still advantages to the EM algorithm:

1. Monotonically increasing. We don't need to worry about overshooting and reducing the log likelihood as we do for gradient based approaches.
2. Respects constraints. EM algorithms are often used for latent multinomial variables, in which means all probabilities must sum to 1. This can be handled with gradient methods via transformations, but a lot of these transformations will have difficulty if the solution is on the boundary (i.e. probabilities exactly equal to 1). EM algorithms don't have issues with this.
3. No need to check the log-likelihood. This is really just an aspect of (1). But I've worked on problems where the EM step is an order of complexity cheaper than computing the log-likelihood. Thus, just evaluating the target function once could take longer than solving the problem!